# I am getting Data in Console Using Angular but I can't render it in html

Tags: node.js, angular, api, angular6

**This is my Page-datail.component.ts**

```
export class PageDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private apiUrl="http://localhost:3000/pages"

  pages={};
  // data={};

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private page:PageService,private router: Router,private http:Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getpage(this.route.snapshot.params['title']);
    // this.getPages();
    // this.getData();

  }
  getpage(title) {
    this.page.getPage(title)
      .subscribe(pages => {
        console.log(pages);
        this.pages = pages;
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

**This is the response I am getting in the Console. I am getting this Object Object Error and it fails to render it in html.**

```
<a *ngFor="let p of pages" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
  {{p.title}}
</a>
```

[This is the response I am getting in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubViI.png)

[image: This is the response I am getting in the console]

Comment: pages needs to be an array

Comment: ngFor directive is applicable to arrays not objects. this.pages is an object not an array and so the error.

Comment: then how can i do that to show the Data

Comment: If you're getting an array in response, define as array like pages = []; But as per your screenshot, it seems that you're getting an object in response. Put {{pages.title}} outside ngFor and you can see 'home'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
export class PageDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  private apiUrl="http://localhost:3000/pages"

  pages=[];
  // data={};

  constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private page:PageService,private router: Router,private http:Http) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getpage(this.route.snapshot.params['title']);
    // this.getPages();
    // this.getData();

  }
  getpage(title) {
    this.page.getPage(title)
      .subscribe(page => {
        console.log(page);
        this.pages.push(page);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is i am getting this that was i am Returning my data in Object not Array I done it this way like

```
{{pages.title}}
```

**and You Can make it to Objects Like this**

```
pages:any={};   //For Objects
page:any=[];    //For Arrays
```